# Postgresql - PSQL encoding issue

Tags: postgresql, encoding, psql

I am trying to set client encoding for a session. I am running the following command on linux terminal (postgresql installed on a remote server.

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U user -d dbase -c "SET client_encoding to 'LATIN1';"
```

Output: SET

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U user -d dbase -c "show client_encoding"
```

Output: UTF8

Why is this happening? Do I need to run this command as a superuser? (I don't think so)

If I run the following commands on Pgadmin4 then it correctly show LATIN1 as the output.

```
SET client_encoding to 'LATIN1'

show client_encoding
```

The server encoding is set to UTF8.

Comment: `SET client_encoding to 'LATIN1';` is not persistent, it is only set for the current session/connection.

Comment: yeah I want it for just one session. if you run the above 2 commands simultaneously then should it not output 'LATIN1' atleast for that session?

Comment: I understood my mistake writing psql command each time creates a new session hence the encoding defaults to original. How do I change it permanently?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the client encoding is only for the current session unless you set the environment variable PGCLIENTENCODING.

From postgresql documentation: *If the environment variable PGCLIENTENCODING is defined in the client's environment, that client encoding is automatically selected when a connection to the server is made.*

So, if you want the client encoding persist try setting this environment var.

Or if you want to execute multiple queries in just one session have a look at the *-f* parameter to set a file to parse.
Ex: `psql -d myDataBase -f myFile`